# Unit testing rails controller, class not receiving method... Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a users controller with a separate `CreateUser` class that when called creates a user.  I have `CreateUser` in my controller and want to make sure that it is being called on.

I'm getting an ActiveRecord error.  Very confused because I'm stubbing out the `CreateUser` class so I'm not touching the database.  Confused why `CreateUser` is not being called on.

What am I doing wrong here?

#### Controller spec:

```
# spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
# ...

describe "create action" do
  before do
    # build fake data
    created_user = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:user)
    result       = double(:context, user: created_user, success?: true)

    # don't hit the database by stubbing creation process
    allow(CreateUser).to receive(:call).and_return(result)
  end

  after do
    post :create, user: { name: "bob" }
  end

  # this test fails
  it "calls on CreateUser interactor" do
    expect(CreateUser).to receive(:call)
  end

  # this test passes
  it "renders something in json" do
    expect(controller).to receive(:render)
  end
end
```

#### Controller:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def create
    result = CreateUser.call # why is this not being called?
    render json: result.user, status: :created
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.permit(:name)
  end
end
```

#### Output:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(CreateUser).to receive(:call)

   (CreateUser (class)).call(*(any args))
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Comment: Could you post relevant parts of `CreateUser`

Comment: is `CreateUser` even relevant?  I'm stubbing out the response to `CreateUser`.  Right now the test is failing because `CreateUser` is not being called on.

Comment: Originally error was because of incorrect strong parameters.  Updated question, still getting error that `CreateUser` is not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was because of CanCan's `load_and_authorize_resource`.  The fix is to stub out that method at top of RSpec test:

```
allow_any_instance_of(CanCan::ControllerResource).to receive(:load_resource)
```